# Word for meant Sarcasm

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that has the same meaning of Sarcasm, however it describes the act of Sarcasm when the person involved actually means what they say (even though it might be a Lie).

e.g: I have this friend who makes this terrible Stew, and whenever she makes it, she tends to put on display, how great it's turned out, and really insists on me trying it and acknowledging how good it is, even though she knows it isn't, and she knows that everyone else knows [it isn't]. So I would tell her *"you're behaving `[fill_in_the_blank]`ly again"*, or, *"you're `[fill_in_the_blank]`ing again"*.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. Can you write an example sentence where this word would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Pretentious? Ostentatious? Silly? I'm a bit confused. Why is "sarcastic" not the right word?

Comment: Sarcasm is supposed to convey the opposite of what is literally being said, but the word I'm looking for is used, when the subject (rather pretentiously) actually mean what they say even though they know it might not be true.

Comment: Isn't she just *lying*? Or are you trying to stress the *enthusiasm* with which she does it? I suppose you could call it *play-acting*. I'd like more clarity on what you're trying to express. For example, they can't *mean what they say* when they *know it's not true* - but they could *behave* as if they thought it was true.

Comment: @Lawrence lying completely fits the situation, however it doesn't capture all of it. It lacks the enthusiasm as you noted. When people think they have to lie about something they usually prefer to avoid the situation in which they have to lie altogether, but this is the exact opposite. This Friend of mine doesn't really care what anyone thinks of her cooking when she's satisfied with it. However when she thinks that it hasn't turned out the way she'd hoped, she tries to convince everyone and probably herself (and I really can't understand why) that it's actually the best.

Comment: Ok, that's much clearer - you should edit it into your question. Does behaving *deceptively* fit the emotional tone you're looking for?

Comment: No. There's Some kind of Desperation in it, though it manifests itself outwardly as unyielding resolution. The Person (subconsciously) thinks, that if they believe enough in something, it will actually come true.

Comment: Are you asking about one specific person in one specific situation?  Is she rational in other respects?  If so, her stew is her "blind spot".

Comment: @ab2, No it happens in all similar situations, i.e: When the results are clearly not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

In the particular situation I'd probably say something like "oh come on, you *are* overselling this a bit".  Which is pretty rude already, but then there probably is not much in the way of politeness for expressing this.  Which is why she's mostly successful in the first place.

Comment: That's pretty much my usual response.

Comment: +1 for "you're overselling [it] again." Along the same lines, perhaps "you're [just] pitching/touting [it] again" could work, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the cook is “delusional,” is behaving “delusionally” and is “deluding him/herself” (as well as “trying to delude” the guests ) with respect to the quality of the stew.

[**delude**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delude) verb (transitive)
1.  (Psychology) to deceive the mind or judgment of; mislead; beguile
(from ‘Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014’, via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)

[**delusion**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delusional) noun
1. a. The act or process of deluding.
b. The state of being deluded.
2. a. A false belief or opinion: labored under the delusion that success was at hand.
delusional adj.
(from ‘American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition’ via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)

(and if delusional/deluding seems to harsh, maybe "[kidding him/herself](http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/kidding-oneself/)" would be more appropriate)

Comment: Deluding is definitely part of it, but I want to know if there's a more precise word for this in english.

Comment: I'd go with this approach but I prefer the more colloquial "You're fooling yourself" or "You're fooling nobody but yourself".

Comment: @DaveM Good point! You're right, that does sound better in the second example/blank and as an adverb for the first blank, "behaving foolishly" definitely makes more sense than "behaving kiddingly." Go for it, it's worth a shot, imo! (but it seems to be a tough crowd out there "tonight"!)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understood what you mean; in your example your friend seems to be in ***denial***

> [***[to be] in denial***](/http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+denial): in a state of refusing to believe something that is true

However, being in denial is something a bit more serious than not acknowledging your stew is terrible. It is more about not accepting a close relative's death or an illness (see the [five stages of grief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model)); it was then applied to lighter situations.

Comment: What I'm trying to describe is not **necessarily** a person who's in denial. They could know what the truth about the matter is, however they try to prove everyone else ( or themselves ) wrong, by trying to gain everyone's approval, and just really insisting on it.

Comment: So you could say the're fighting a lost cause?

Comment: Kind of, though they do it with a lot of will power, and prevail a lot of the times, at least to the external onlooker.

Comment: I'm not entirely catching the tenor of the cook's remark, nor why she is saying it - but I feel fairly certain that whatever it is, could not strictly be called *sarcasm*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're aiming at, but I could suggest **playing dumb**.

> **Play dumb:** to pretend to not know or not understand something

Comment: Playing Dumb *might be* part of it. I say might, because sometimes the person actually does (makes themself) believe it.